# Pluralization in laravel blade @lang() localization?

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-blade, pluralize

Laravel 5 provides translations using the @lang helper

```
<!-- file: template.blade.php -->
@lang('some text')
```

Laravel 5 also has the possibility to pluralize strings depending on a variable.

```
// file: controller.php
echo trans_choice('messages.apples', 10);
```

The translation file would then contain the following line to translate apples:

```
// file: /resources/lang/en
'apples' => 'There is one apple|There are many apples',
```

Now, I would like to use pluralization inside a blade template and I cannot find out how to use this. I tried the following:

```
<!-- file: template.blade.php -->
Course duration: {{ $course.days }} @lang('day|days', $course.days)
```

which feels to be the logical syntax to me, but this only give me an error about input argument 2 needing to be an array. I also tried this:

```
<!-- file: template.blade.php -->
Course duration: {{ $course.days }} @lang('day|days', [$course.days])
```

And this:

```
<!-- file: template.blade.php -->
Course duration: {{ $course.days }} @lang(['day|days', $course.days])
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a `@choice` blade directive for this.

```
Course duration: {{ $course->days }} @choice('day|days', $course->days)
```

Comment: Is that included by default? I thought something like that would be useful but never found it in documentations...

Comment: This works great. I combined it with the answer of D. Petrov. ```@choice('plurals.days', $course->days)```

Comment: It would be interesting if you could choose between two translations ;)

Comment: On Laravel 7, using the resources/lang/lang.json I use: @choice('day',2)  and this choice means get the string after the pipe so it shows 'days' on the translation language

Comment: Laravel 8.69.0, `@choice` directive doesn't work ? Always returns first parameter before pipe, any idea ??

Answer (score 6):

You can use it with variables like this

```php
//plurals.php
'day' => 'one day| :n days',
```

you can do this in blade file:

```
{{ trans_choice('plurals.day', $course->days), ['n' => $course->days] }}
```

you can even use this

```
{{ trans_choice('plurals.like', $post->likes), ['n' => $post->likes] }}
```

```
'like' => '{0} Nobody likes this|[1,19] :n users like this|[20,*] Many users like this'
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to register a new keyed entry in one of your translation files, let's say `plurals.php`. Then the proper approach would be:

```
//in plurals.php
//...
'day' => 'day|days',
//...
```

Then you can retrieve the entry like

```
{{trans_choice('plurals.day', $course->days)}} //assuming the arrow syntax is how you retrieve a property in php :P
```